# How to convert Cookie String to JSON using Swift

Tags: json, swift, string, cookies

```
   ("Global_Data"): {
       Created = 574049501;
       Domain = "";
       Expires = "2019-03-19 02:11:40 +0000";
       Name = "Data";
       Path = "/";
       Value = "%7B%22countryISO%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22cultureCode%22%3A%22en-GB%22%2C%22currencyCode%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22apiVersion%22%3A%222.1.4%22%7D;
       Version = 1;
    }
```

On grabbing a Cookie data from a webview i got the Value => as a string 
with some characters knowing these characters represent special characters or letters.
How can i convert it to a JSON format. Thanks

> "%7B%22countryISO%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22cultureCode%22%3A%22en-GB%22%2C%22currencyCode%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22apiVersion%22%3A%222.1.4%22%7D"

Answer (score 2):

Your string is already a JSON string you just have to remove the percent encoding from it, create a custom structure that conform to Decodable and you are all set:

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let countryISO, cultureCode, currencyCode, apiVersion: String
}
```

---

```
let string = "%7B%22countryISO%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22cultureCode%22%3A%22en-GB%22%2C%22currencyCode%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22apiVersion%22%3A%222.1.4%22%7D"

let json = string.removingPercentEncoding ?? ""
```

> "{"countryISO":"US","cultureCode":"en-GB","currencyCode":"USD","apiVersion":"2.1.4"}"

```
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(root.countryISO)    // "US"
    print(root.cultureCode)   // "en-GB"
    print(root.currencyCode)  // "USD"
    print(root.apiVersion)    // "2.1.4"
} catch {
    print(error) 
}
```